Windows search with attribute value via QGIS actions
I'm trying to build an action using Python in QGIS. By clicking an object the Windows explorer should open a specific directory and search for the value given in the column named "REG_NR".
As long as the query string is static (f.e. 'street') the opening of the directory and the search are working fine. As soon as I replace the static value with the column name '[%REG_NR%]' the explorer.exe warns:

"" couldn't be found. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try
again.

As I said, it works perfectly fine with a static search term. The values of the intended columns look like this:
1103/50

2204/336

3309/227
...

This is the code-snippet I used:
import subprocess

query_string = '[%REG_NR%]'
local_path = r'C:\Users\X\Y' # r is raw for dealing with backslashes

#for a local folder
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer /root,"search-ms:query={query_string}&crumb=location:{local_path}&"')

EDIT:
I can run the action successfully with columns/attributes that only contain text, so I think the format of the column or the "/" within the attributes values cause the problem.

I guess it should be '[% "REG_NR" %]'.

Hi, thanks for the advice! Unfortunately '[% "REG_NR" %]' results in the same warning as described above...

The Microsoft search-ms documentation states the query parameter is to be URL encoded.



Parameter
Value
Description




query
URL-encoded text
The query text entered by the user.



You can URL encode in Python with urllib.parse.urlencode E.g.
from urllib.parse import urlencode

query_string = urlencode({"query": "A/B"})
print(query_string)

Output:
query=A%2FB

I'm unable to test as I'm not using Windows, but something like the following may work:
import subprocess
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# URL Encode the query. 
query_string = urlencode({"query": "[%REG_NR%]"})
local_path = r'C:\Users\X\Y' # r is raw for dealing with backslashes

#for a local folder
#Note {query_string} contains "query=etc..."
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer /root,"search-ms:{query}&crumb=location:{local_path}&"')


@Thomas did this answer your question? If so, consider accepting it or providing feedback so it can be improved.
